# Why does my android app report that it cannot "find" my own class? possibly related to proguard?

Tags: android, proguard

Im developing an android app, and recently started using proguard due to the "# of classes" that the library contained.

In this process, I have been able to add proguard rules and finally recompile my app and even "run" it.

Only each time that I "run" it, it errors out and reports that

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.myCompany.myModule.Utils" on path: DexPathList...
```

Since proguard has been implemented in order to reduce the total number of classes, I use proguard on every build.  I would be dollars to donuts that the problem lies in that file - because the app ran smoothly before it was added.
I have added the following lines to my proguard.pro file in android studio to try to force this to be resolved:

```
-keepclassmembers class com.myCompany.myModule
-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application

-keepclasseswithmembers class com.myCompany.myModule.** { *; }
-keepclasseswithmembers class com.myCompany.myModule.Utils {*;}
```

However, this does not solve the problem.

I am at a loss because my application errors out immediately on startup.  Do you have any ideas on what can fix this?

Comment: I solved it!  It's really weird, but I changed the class "Utils" from a "public class" to a "public final class" and it ran without problems.  Whew!  That was a day I won't ever get back

Comment: In what circumstances are you using the `Utils` class? Try adding this line: `-keep class com.myCompany.myModule.Utils {*;}`.

Comment: Thanks, that is already in the proguard config file, as shown above...

Answer (score 0):

If you get a ClassNotFoundException, you should keep the class like this:

```
-keep class com.myCompany.myModule.Utils
```

The option -keepclassmembers only keeps the specified class members (fields and methods).

The option -keepclasseswithmembers only keeps classes that have the specified class members (and those members).

See the ProGuard manual > Usage > [Overview of Keep Options](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/usage.html#keepoverview).